# Laravel - Order by ASC / DESC with button or a href

Tags: php, laravel

I've a trouble with ordering with button or `a href` element.

I want something like, after **click button - order by lowest price**, it will order by lowest price, but I don't know, how to do that.

I've tried lot of functions, but any of them work. Any ideas please?

[image: connect to db and taking data to variable]

[image: foreach, which i want to order by asc and desc with buttons]

Comment: @turivishal, What is this edit for? Does it make the question more answarable? Code it images is bad, we should stay away from this kind of edits

Comment: Okay @vega, i will keep in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass something like `?sort=asc` inside the URL and inside the Controller do the following:

```
public function getSomething(Request $request)
{
    $inputs = $request->all();

    $query = SomeModel::where('column_x', 'value');
    if (isset($inputs['sort']) && $inputs['sort'] === 'desc') {
        $query->orderBy('column_y', 'DESC');
    } else {
        $query->orderBy('column_y');
    }

    // continue with your logic...
}
```